# How to aggregate page node on one node with many relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

(Link)-[:`INCOMING-INNERLINK`]->(Page)
I have many links that point to the same page. How can I aggregate all the link nodes to one node with many relations within the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply `MATCH` the `Link` and `Page` nodes and create a new relationship between all distinct pairs:

```
MATCH (l:Link)-[:INCOMING-INNERLINK]->(p:Page)
WITH DISTINCT l, p
CREATE UNIQUE (l)-[:SINGLE_LINK_REL]->(p)
```

Comment: The probleme here that i wanna regroub the links by the one properties : if i have page <-link1(anchortext ="test1") page <-link2(anchortext ="test1") page <-link3(anchortext ="test3") The Result should be something like this : page <- link1(anchorText="text1") (2 relation between page and link1) page <- link3(anchorText="text2") (1relation between page and link3) hope im clear and Thanks for your response @Martin Preusse

Comment: Regroup? How? Why and by what criterion is the relationship between `link2` and `page` removed? Try to describe it more clearly in a new question.